# calculating from a timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time

Yesterday I asked another question to calculate time.

Now I realized, that it makes no sense to use a second table for my project because everything that is necessary is already given in my first table. So, for the moment I use two tables where I insert two timestamps:

```
$time = "INSERT INTO table2 ( a, b, c) VALUES (NOW(),NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY,(unix_timestamp(NOW()+ INTERVAL 14 DAY)) - unix_timestamp(NOW()))";
```

Like I already said, it could be much easier and the same result will be reached without a second table. Now my problem is, this is the first time I have worked with timefunctions in php. There are a lot of different functions that I do not really understand.

I think to solve my problem I can use something like:

```
$row = fetch_assoc()
$old_timestamp = $row->b;

$actual_time = mktime(); //which makes an actual timestamp
$seconds = '1209600'; //which is exactly the timeperiod of 14 days
$added = $old_timestamp + $seconds; //which adds the seconds to the old timestamp and should be the same as NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY from the VALUE of the query
$date_to_check = $added - $actual_time;
   if $date_to_check <= 0 { 
     do something }
```

Is this possible? I would really appreciate if there is someone who can help. thanks a lot.

**UPDATE**

For everyone who likes to know what i have in mind. Here is the code for the actual way:

```
$time_check = $db->query("SELECT (B <= NOW()) AS var FROM table2 WHERE x='$x'");         
            while ($row = $time_check->fetch_object()){ 
                if (($row->var != 0) && ($var1 === '0')){
                        $update_status = $db->query("UPDATE table1 SET var1='1' WHERE x='$x'");{
                            $delete_timecount = $db->query("DELETE FROM table2 WHERE x='$x'");
                        }
                }
            }
```

I would like to accomplish the same result without a second table.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: i would like to change a setting after a registration and a time of 14 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really understand what you are trying to do. It appears that you are trying to recognize when 14 days have elapsed after someone's registration in order to do something.

```
if (time() > $old_timestamp + 1209600) {
    // It's been 14 days
    // Do something
}
```

I used [`time`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php), which simply returns the current time. Do you understand what a [timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is?

Comment: i updated my question but i think this could be the solution.

Comment: this seems to be wrong. the update will be executed even in case when 14 days not have passed.

Comment: @bonny Fixed, try it now. I think I had my operator reversed.